# How to disable sstate-cache per recipe in Yocto

Tags: yocto, bitbake

I have some self written yocto recipes, which create issues with the yocto sstate-cache mechanism (like not rebuilding the recipe when dependencies have changed). **Is there a way to disable sstate-caching on a per recipe basis?**

Searching the interwebs I can only find very old and by now broken mechanisms:

https://patchwork.openembedded.org/patch/17039/

Or only partial disable functions:

https://patchwork.openembedded.org/patch/130719/

My Yocto version is Zeus and above.

Thanks and cheers!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the recipe:

```py
SSTATE_SKIP_CREATION = "1"
```

or, from outside the recipe (e.g. `local.conf`):

```py
SSTATE_SKIP_CREATION_pn-recipefoo = "1"
SSTATE_SKIP_CREATION_pn-recipebar = "1"
```

---

You can verify if sstate exists for a recipe, using `oe-check-sstate`, e.g.:

```sh
oe-check-sstate yourimage | grep recipefoo
```

and you can remove sstate for a recipe using:

```sh
bitbake -c cleansstate recipefoo
```

**However**, it is concerning that your recipe interferes with the sstate mechanism. Ensure that you are correctly setting & updating the version and revision of your packages whenever the source code changes.

If your recipe source is stored alongside your Yocto metadata, consider [using `externalsrc` to reference it](https://docs.yoctoproject.org/dev-manual/common-tasks.html#building-software-from-an-external-source), allowing Yocto to better track changes.

Comment: Thanks @Justin for the detailed answer! I was setting PV to a constant value while grabbing git branch head. Only since SSTATE is enabled this became a problem.

May I add another follow up question to your remark about source alongside metadata: What if my bb recipe only copies files from the meta layer to the image, but doesn't run compilation. Is externalsrc still the right way to go? The documentation reads more like build code located outside of the yocto structure...

Comment: SSTATE_SKIP_CREATION also works on a per task basis. 

Suppose you want so disable cache for the 'do_package' task. Add the following to the .bb:
SSTATE_SKIP_CREATION_task-package = '1'

Note that the 'do_' is omitted